# Namespaces con soap

Tags: php, soap

Tengo un problema.
tengo que acceder a el siguiente servicio:

```
POST /ws/emision.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.123:8070
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://DCX/Emision/ConsultaSumaAseguradaVehiculos"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <UserCredentials xmlns="http://DCX/Emision/">
      <IdUsuario>string</IdUsuario>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </UserCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ConsultaSumaAseguradaVehiculos xmlns="http://DCX/Emision/">
      <Anio>int</Anio>
      <IdAutoModelo>int</IdAutoModelo>
      <CodigoInfoAuto>string</CodigoInfoAuto>
    </ConsultaSumaAseguradaVehiculos>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

y me devuelve :
El servidor no reconoció el valor del encabezado HTTP SOAPAction: http://DCX/Emision/ConsultaSumaAseguradaVehiculos.

El codigo implementado :

```
 $opts = array(
        'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
    );
    $params = array (
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
        'verifypeer' => false, 
        'verifyhost' => false, 
        'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1', 
        'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 
        'connection_timeout' => 180, 
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) ,
        'xmlns' => 'http://DCX/Emision/',
    );

    $apiauth =array('IdUsuario'=>'','Password'=>'');
    $wsdl    = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.123:8070/ws/emision.asmx?WSDL";
    $leyenda = 'http://DCX/Emision/' ;


    $params=array(
    'Anio'=>2013,
    'IdAutoModelo'=>360685,
    'CodigoInfoAuto'=>'0360685'
    );

 $header  = new SoapHeader($leyenda, 'UserCredentials', $apiauth);


  try{
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl); 


    $soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);       


    $response = $soap->__soapCall('ConsultaSumaAseguradaVehiculos', array($params)); 
}
```

No entiendo cual es el problema. estuve revisando y al parecer esta bien implementado. Agradezco la colaboración que puedan hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentado acceder a un servicio web con SOAP y está pasando un parámetro SOAPAction en la solicitud HTTP que no coincide con lo que el servicio espera.

Valida que estas utilizando el correcto, pueda ser que al servicio web le hayan realizado alguna modificación como cambiar el namespace (espacio de nombres del servicio).

Te recomiendo que realices pruebas en SOAPUI u otro ya que ellos te van a mostrar el SOAPAction que este en uso.

Suerte.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, voy a probar con soapui y comento luego.